# list groups with text in displayname

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Using the graph api documentation I read that its possible to list all the groups within a tenant ( /groups endpoint) and its possible to use startswith or eq in displayname query. I was wondering if there is a way so search for groups with a specific text in the group displayname. Contains and endswith are not supported. If possible I want to prevent code that reads all groups and searches within the result.

Answer (score 0):

Currently filter parameters for Graph API's does not support "contains". Check this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters

Comment: That is exactly what I noticed. I'm just wondering if there are plans for implementing this

Comment: Beta endpoints may offer more flexibility for queries in future. We do not have any ETA to share.